# How do I use Hyper-V to have multiple people using one computer?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

This may not be exactly an original question, but I couldn't find any good answers to it.
I want to know how, using Hyper-V, I can have two desktops running with one keyboard controlling one, one mouse controlling one, for both OS's.

I already have the VM set up running Windows 10, and the host PC is running windows 10.

***I DO NOT WANT TO JUST REMOTE INTO THE VM USING ANOTHER PC***

I know that this is what most people would suggest, but that is not what I wish to do. I want to have two keyboards and two mice plugged into this computer for my own reasons. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Anything is possible

Comment: No, its not.  HyperV isnt designed to do this, and it won't work.  For usb redirection to work, you need a SERVER os with RemoteFX, which IIRC costs per virtual.  And you still need to use RDC.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817581(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called [SoftXpand](http://www.miniframe.com/) that may do what you want.

It can split a computer into workstations using several GPUs, split USB devices, sound, etc.

It costs money but there is a free trial. There are also alternatives like [ASTER](http://www.ibik.ru/) that have better licensing, but I mentioned SoftXpand because it is better known. There are known [issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHc9H.png) with SoftXpand licensing.

Comment: this has nothing to do with hyperV. Yes there are lots of [multiseating tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration) but they don't use Hyper-V or any virtualization solutions under the hood

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your approach:

- Hyper-V is a virtualisation platform, and as such is not ment for the workload you are throwing at it.
- While Mouse and Keyboard are one part of the equation (the easier one), the two displays with two grahpic cards are another

That said, you could try an approach, where:

- You have Pairs of USB Keyboards/Mice attached to the two VMs via USB redirection
- You have 3 graphics cards, with one belonging to Hyper-V and the two others attached to the two VMs as PCI-Express devices.

This could theoretically work, but be advised: This is NOT what Hyper-V was built for, so you are in unsupoorted territory.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without three gpus? And aren't you always in unsupported territory with VM's lol.

Comment: Assuming you want not only 2 keyboards, but also 2 displays, you will need those: Hyper-V Server (as opposed to full Windows server) doesn't support local viewing.

Comment: So would doing a VM of windows server 2012 and then making another VM inside that accomplish what I want?

Comment: Not at all. The important part is, that you need to plug in at least 2, in reality 3 displays - and that the GPUs for these displays must be split to the 2 VMs and the Host. In reality this means you need 3 GPUs.

Comment: Ok then, thanks for the help! If there is a way to VM my GPU so that I dont have to buy two more that would be great :P

Comment: You can use the virtualised GPUs, but they are unfit for anything but office work, and again you need to display them on two monitors - which Hyper-V server does not allow.